# fetch data and show it in textbox with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

As you can see my current code doesnt work and i need your help guys...i want to filter in my search(textbox) and show the data filtered in there corresponding textboxes...can anyone help make my code work?? i've been looking in google for hours already for the same idea of my program that works but i cant find any help me please.

example expected output:

[image]

html code:

```
<form method="post">
Search batchcode: <input type="text" id="query" /><br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
ID: <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="id1" /> <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="id2" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Name: <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="name1" /> <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="name2" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 1: <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="optA1" /> <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="optA2" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 2: <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="optB1" /> <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="optB2" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Other Qualification: <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="other_qual1" /> <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="other_qual2" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Interview: <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="interview1" /> <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="interview2" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Total: <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="total1" /> <br />
<input id="result" type="text" name="total2" /> <br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[name^=search]').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
url:"search.php",
type:"POST",
data : { term : $('#query').val() },
dataType:json,
success : function(result) {
alert(result);
            }
        });
    })
});      
</script>
```

search.php page:

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['term'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score WHERE batchcode LIKE '$q%'");

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$data[]=array('value'=>$row['batchcode']);
        $id[] = $row['id'];
        $name[] = $row['name'];
        $score1[] = $row['score1'];
        $score2[] = $row['score2'];
        $other_qual[] = $row['other_qual'];
        $interview[] = $row['interview'];
        $total[] = $row['total'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Care this is very bad: **"SELECT * FROM score WHERE batchcode LIKE '$q%'"**. You need to use mysqli_real_escape($q) or prepared statement in order to avoid vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your php file before you echo out the result:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and to show data in a textbox I would do something like:

```
$("#element").val(result.value);
```

As others have pointed out in the comments you should definitely use PDO or mysqli to fetch data from the db.

Comment: where should i put the "$("#element").val(result.value);" in the script or in the texbox?

Comment: Shouldn't it work if you put it right next to or where the `alert` code is?

Comment: Oh right, and don't forget to change `$q = $_GET['term'];` to `$q = $_POST['term'];` (since you have specified the form to be sent via POST method).

Comment: still no data showing in the correspoding(textboxes) :(

Comment: Try deleting the code: `$data = array();` and changing `$data[]=array('value'=>$row['batchcode']);` to `$data =array('value'=>$row['batchcode']);`

Comment: Can you show how you fetched the data to the input field?

Comment: what do you mean fetch the data in the input field? in the (id=query) from search(textbox)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46563/discussion-between-daniel-lisik-and-user3235574)

Comment: Hey, I thought of another thing to try: in the beginning of search.php, add this: `if (isset($_POST['term'])) {`, and in the end of the file, right before `?>`, add `}`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any "search" button to click handler.
Try to add the button after search input, like this:

```
Search batchcode: <input type="text" id="query" /><br />
<input type="button" id="search" value="Search"/>
```